# Get z-index of selected object in fabric js

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to get the z-index of selected object in fabric js. Is there a way to get that?

```
var z_index = 1;
$('#manage_index').change(function(){
    var cur_value = $(this).val();
    if(cur_value!='')
    {
        var object = canvas.getActiveObject();
        if(cur_value=='up') // Means increase z-index
        {
            canvas.moveTo(object, z_index);
            z_index = z_index + 1;
        }
        else if(cur_value=='back') //Means decrease z-index
        {

            //var temp_index = 0; // If set it to 0, it will goes into backward, 
            //But i am trying to implement something like below
            var temp_index = canvas.get('z-index');// Get the z-index of selected object and then decrease it
            canvas.moveTo(object, temp_index-1);
        }
    }
     $(this).val('');
});
```

Comment: do you want to change the object order??

Comment: @Durga Yes, i am trying to implement forward/backward feature, kind of z-index. Means move object to upward or backward. Lets say there is 5 object in canvas and if i selected one of them i am trying to get the z-index of that selected object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('a');
canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
 left:50,
 top:50,
 height:50,
 width:50,
 fill:'red'
}));
canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
 left:70,
 top:70,
 height:50,
 width:50,
 fill:'green'
}));
canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
 left:90,
 top:90,
 height:50,
 width:50,
 fill:'blue'
}));
canvas.renderAll();
function getIndex(){
 var activeObj = canvas.getActiveObject();
 console.log(activeObj && canvas.getObjects().indexOf(activeObj));
}
function bringToFront(){
 var activeObj = canvas.getActiveObject();
 activeObj && canvas.bringToFront(activeObj).discardActiveObject(activeObj).renderAll();
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.19/fabric.js"></script>
<button onclick='getIndex()'>Index</button>
<button onclick='bringToFront()'>bringToFront</button>
<canvas id="a" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

As fabric object stores in an array , you can get index using `indexOf`. to rearrange order you can use the [bringToFront](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#bringToFront), [bringForward](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#bringForward), [sendBackwards](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#sendBackwards), [sendToBack](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#sendToBack). And [moveTo](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#moveTo) with to specified index.

Comment: @DS9 Happy coding ;)

Answer (score 4):

I thought it was already implemented in recent Fabric.js versions but you can still extend Fabric objects prototype :

```
fabric.Object.prototype.getZIndex = function() {
    return this.canvas.getObjects().indexOf(this);
}
```